# How to find non repeated numbers in an Array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Dear all I'm trying to find non repeated value in an array using javascript.I have written some code but it not working properly ..can you guys tell me where is the problem.thanks.

```js
var arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];
var n = arr.length;
var result = '';

function nonrep() {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      if (i != j && arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        result = arr[i];
        break;
      }
    if (j == n)
      return arr[i];
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(nonrep())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in an array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: `arr.lenght` Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need the unique values or values appear only once in the array?

Comment: TYPO, Use `length` and your code will work

Comment: it's not giving proper result ..can you help please.

Comment: that is spell mistake

Comment: `var result = '';` why do you initialize `result` to be a string? You need an array, don't you?

Answer (score 4):

Some changes:

- Move all variable declarations inside of the function.
- Use a function parameter for the handed over array, keep the function pure.
- Declare all needed variables at top of the function in advance.
- Take an array as result array `unique`.
- Check `i` and `j` and if equal `continue` the (inner) loop.
- Check the value at `i` and `j` and exit the (inner) loop, because a duplicate is found.
- Take the check at the end of the inner loop and check the index `j` with the length of the array `l`, and if equal push the value to `unique`.
- Use a single `return` statement with `unique` array at the end of the outer loop.

```js
function getUnique(array) {
    var l = array.length,
        i, j,
        unique = [];

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if (i === j) {
                continue;
            }
            if (array[i] === array[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j === l) {
            unique.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return unique;
}

console.log(getUnique([-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3]));
```

Another solution could be to check if `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` returns the same value. Then you found a unique value.

```js
var array = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3],
    unique = array.filter((v, i) => array.indexOf(v) === array.lastIndexOf(v));

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Although as always you bring to light fascinating concepts, this time I will have to point the O(2N^2) complexity is redundant. Just an observation though.

Answer (score 4):

There is possibly a more neat approach to this solution, but this works as expected by filtering the array and compare it's current value with the array items itself (expect current item's index value).

```js
const sampleArray = [1,2,3,7,2,1,3];
const getNonDuplicatedValues = (arr) => 
    arr.filter((item,index) => {
      arr.splice(index,1)
      const unique = !arr.includes(item)
      arr.splice(index,0,item)
      return unique
  })

console.log("Non duplicated values: " , ...getNonDuplicatedValues(sampleArray))
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
 const arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];
    
    
    const non_repeating = arr.filter(num => arr.indexOf(num) === arr.lastIndexOf(num))
    
    console.log(non_repeating)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first use `reduce` to get one object with count for each number element and then `filter` on `Object.keys` to return array of non-repeating numbers.

```js
var arr=[-1,2,5,6,2,9,-1,6,5,-1,3];
var obj = arr.reduce((r, e) => (r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1, r), {});
var uniq = Object.keys(obj).filter(e => obj[e] == 1).map(Number)

console.log(uniq)
```

Solution with `for` loop.

```js
var arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];

var uniq = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j) break;
    else if (j == arr.length - 1) uniq.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach

```js
var arr = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5];

let duplicateArr = [];
var repeatorCheck = (item) => {
  const currentItemCount = arr.filter(val => val=== item).length;
  if(currentItemCount > 1) duplicateArr.push(item);
  return currentItemCount;
}
var result = arr.filter((item,index) => {
  var itemRepeaterCheck = !duplicateArr.includes(item) && repeatorCheck(item);
  if(itemRepeaterCheck === 1){
    return item;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5];

    function nonRepeatableNo(arr) {
        let val = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let count = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
                    count += 1
                }
            }
            if (count === 1) {
                val.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
        console.log(val)
    }
    nonRepeatableNo(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Filtering only unique elements according to OP request:

This uses for loops, as requested. It returns an array containing only elements appearing once in the original array.

```js
var arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];
var n = arr.length;
var result = [];

function nonrep() {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j=0 ; j < n; j++)
      if (i!=j && arr[i]==arr[j])
        break;
    if(j==n)
        result.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(nonrep())
```

Comment: i need solution in for loop and also above code not working

Comment: @Anilkumar I edited my answer and used for loops, implementing the filtering you requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [45, 4,16,25,45,4,16, 9,7, 16, 25];
 var arr=arr1.sort();
  console.log(arr);
 var str=[];
 arr.filter(function(value){

if( arr.indexOf(value) === arr.lastIndexOf(value))
{ str.push(value);
console.log("ntttttttttttttnnn" +str)

}// how this works ===============A
 })
```

O/P

```
 7,9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try the below code snippet.

var arr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];
    var uniqArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j) break;
        else if (j == arr.length - 1){
          uniqArr.push(arr[i])
        } 
      }
    }

    console.log(uniqArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

this ES6 code worked for me :

a.map(c=>a.filter(b=>c==b)).filter(e=>e.length<2).reduce((total, cur)=> total.concat(cur), [])

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working method with loops.

```js
  var arr = [-1,2,5,6,2,9,-1,6,5,-1,3];
  var len = arr.length;
  const result = arr
        .filter(value=>{
              var count=0;
              for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
              {
                  if(arr[i]===value)
                    count++;
              }
              return count===1;
          })
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sampleArr = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3];

function getUnique(arr){
  const result=[]
  const obj={}
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(!obj[arr[i]]){
      obj[arr[i]]=true
      result.push(arr[i])
    }else{
      const index= result.indexOf(arr[i])
      if(index!==-1){
        result.splice(result.indexOf(arr[i]),1)
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}

const uniqueArr= getUnique(sampleArr)
console.log(uniqueArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..

```js
var x = [1,1,2,3,2,4]
var res = []
x.map(d => {
  if(res.includes(d)) {
    // remove value from array
    res = res.filter((a) => a!=d)
  } else {
    // add value to array
    res.push(d)
  }
})
console.log(res) // [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//without using any filter also with minimum complexity
```

```js
const array = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8,1,1 ];
const unique = new Set(); 
const repetedTreses = new Set();
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(!unique.has(array[i]) && !repetedTreses.has(array[i])){
        unique.add(array[i]);
    }else{
        repetedTreses.add(array[i]);
        unique.delete(array[i]);
    }
}
let uniqueElements=[...unique];
console.log(uniqueElements);
```

Comment: Hi! please read [answer] add some description to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 4];

const getNonDuplicatedValues = () => {
  let nondup = [];
  arr.forEach((e) => {
    if (nondup.includes(e)) {
      let index = nondup.indexOf(e);
      nondup.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      nondup.push(e);
    }
  });
  return nondup;
};

const Nondup = getNonDuplicatedValues();

console.log("Nondup", Nondup);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for that:

```
console.log(
  [-1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 9, -1, 6, 5, -1, 3].filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v, i + 1) === -1 )
);
```