# How does array.filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item) === index) work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How does array.filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item) === index) work?

I'm aware the that filter method iterates over all the items in the array, but how does this method work when you add in index as a parameter too? Does it then iterate over entire set of pairs of (item, index)?

I'm trying to find the unique element in an array in which every element is duplicated apart from one. e.g. [1,1,2], [1,2,3,2,1], etc

Comment: Did you read the documentation for filter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `index` is the position of `item` in `array`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854750/how-to-find-non-repeated-numbers-in-an-array-using-javascript

Comment: The index won't help much for determining unique elements. Walk through the input array, keeping track of numbers you've seen by adding them to a set. For each number, push it to the output if it's not in the set or ===1. Then add it to the set

Answer (score 1):

When you add an index the index parameter will be the index of the element that the iteration is happening on, for example:

```
const myArray = [a, b, c]
myArray.filter((item, index) => {console.log(`The item ${item} is on index ${index} on the array`)}
```

That will print

```
$ The item a is on index 0 on the array
$ The item b is on index 1 on the array
$ The item c is on index 2 on the array
```

See more infromatiom on [MDN page for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: So with array.filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item) === index), if we let array = [1, 1, 2], the inputs for (item, index) are (1, 0), (1,1), (2,2)?

Comment: In this case you are not printing anything if you wanted that result you would have to make a console.log(item, index)

Comment: Array.filter make a new array if the item pass the test in this case all of them would have passed the test, if you stored the returned value in a variable you would ended up with the same array

Comment: how does all of them pass the test? the only pair that works is (1,1)?

Comment: Because array.indexOf(item) === index returns true so it pass in the test

Comment: This condition seems trivial to me array.indexOf(item) === index, wouldn't the LHS equal to the RHS always since they're both ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: In the first iteration we have item = 1 and index=0 so array.indexOf(item) is equal to 0, 0 === 0 so it returns trur

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
['a','b','c'].filter((item, index) => console.log(item, index))
```

It basically iterates through each item and its index.

Comment: so like (a,0) then (b, 1) then (c, 2)?

Comment: Exactly, you can try it your own in a console. https://jsconsole.com/